# In a listing, how to have line numbers not in margin?

Tags: listings, margins, two-column

I'm using listings with line numbers in a two-column document. When the listing is in the right column, the numbers are too close to the text on the left.

I tried using `xleftmargin`, but that option also moves the caption to the right.

How can I move only the code and the line numbers to the right, so that they are no longer in the margin?

[image]

MWE ([ieeetran.cls](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html)):

```
\documentclass[english,conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{captionpos=b}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
\lstset{showstringspaces=false, columns=flexible, keepspaces=true}
\lstset{tabsize=2, gobble=2}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, numberfirstline=true, firstnumber=1, stepnumber=5}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{author}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\blindtext[4]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    mah figure
    \caption{This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.}
    \label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.},label=mylisting]
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `xleftmargin = <a sensible length>`

Comment: Is `numbers=right` an option, maybe together with `xrightmargin=1.2em`?

Comment: @gernot `numbers=right` makes it really hard to see which number belongs to which line when the lines are short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To shift the numbers but not the caption requires to dig deeper into the `listings` package.

Instead of the `\lst@PlaceNumber` command without arguments we define `\lst@FormatNumber` which takes the number as an argument. This allows us to print also nothing but occupying the same space. We define a new value for the option `numbers` called `LEFT` for numbers not in the margin; most of the code is a copy of the original code.

```
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\relax}%   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\llap{\normalfont % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
                \lst@numberstyle{##1}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\rlap{\normalfont % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{##1}}}\\%
     LEFT&\def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\makebox[\lst@LEFTmargin][r]{\normalfont  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                \lst@numberstyle{##1}\kern\lst@numbersep}}% <<<<<<<<<<
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
```

Moreover, we have to extend the printing of the number by an else branch such that an 'empty' number is printed in unnumbered lines.

```
\gdef\lst@SkipOrPrintLabel{%
    \ifnum\lst@skipnumbers=\z@
        \global\advance\lst@skipnumbers-\lst@stepnumber\relax
        \lst@FormatNumber{\thelstnumber}%     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \lst@numberfirstlinefalse
    \else
        \lst@ifnumberfirstline
            \lst@FormatNumber{\thelstnumber}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \lst@numberfirstlinefalse
        \else                               % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \lst@FormatNumber{}%              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \fi
    \fi
    \global\advance\lst@skipnumbers\@ne
}
```

Finally, to control the width reserved for the number, we introduce a new key `LEFTmargin` with default value `2em`.

```
\lst@Key{LEFTmargin}{2em}{\def\lst@LEFTmargin{#1}}
```

If these definitions are included in the preamble instead of in a file loaded by `\usepackage`, they have to be enclosed by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Here is the sample code from the original posting.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{captionpos=b}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
\lstset{showstringspaces=false, columns=flexible, keepspaces=true}
\lstset{tabsize=2, gobble=2}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt,
   numberfirstline=true, firstnumber=1, stepnumber=5}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\relax}%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{##1}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{##1}}}\\%
     LEFT&\def\lst@FormatNumber##1{\makebox[\lst@LEFTmargin][r]{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{##1}\kern\lst@numbersep}}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\gdef\lst@SkipOrPrintLabel{%
    \ifnum\lst@skipnumbers=\z@
        \global\advance\lst@skipnumbers-\lst@stepnumber\relax
        \lst@FormatNumber{\thelstnumber}%
        \lst@numberfirstlinefalse
    \else
        \lst@ifnumberfirstline
            \lst@FormatNumber{\thelstnumber}%
            \lst@numberfirstlinefalse
        \else
            \lst@FormatNumber{}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \global\advance\lst@skipnumbers\@ne
}
\lst@Key{LEFTmargin}{2em}{\def\lst@LEFTmargin{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{The Title}
\author{author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\blindtext[4]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    mah figure
    \caption{This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.}
    \label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=LEFT,LEFTmargin=1.2em,numbersep=2pt,float,caption={This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.},label=mylisting]
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. (I just noticed that this problem does not occur with ACM two-column layouts. I wonder what they are doing different...)

Answer (score 8):

I think the only way to shift the code to the right is using `xleftmargin`.

```
\lstset{xleftmargin=2em} % or some other value
```

If you want the caption to stay unshifted, I would suggest not to use the float parameter, but to use a separate float environment.

```
\documentclass[english,conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{listing}{tbp}{lol}
\floatname{listing}{Listing}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
\lstset{showstringspaces=false, columns=flexible, keepspaces=true}
\lstset{tabsize=2, gobble=2}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, numberfirstline=true, firstnumber=1, stepnumber=5}
\lstset{xleftmargin=2em}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{author}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\blindtext[4]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    mah figure
    \caption{This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.}
    \label{myfig}
  \end{figure}

\begin{listing}
\begin{lstlisting}
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.}
\label{mylisting}
\end{listing}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I came up with the same 'solution' but found that this parameter shifts the whole float including the caption, which then protrudes into the right margin.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that `xleftmargin` does not work properly.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Now I have updated my answer with a solution that keeps the caption to the left.

Comment: Would you mind to post the complete code (i.e., a compilable document)?

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xleftmargin=1em` or something like that and reduce the `columnwidth` for the listing by the same amount.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{captionpos=b}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
\lstset{showstringspaces=false, columns=flexible, keepspaces=true}
\lstset{tabsize=2, gobble=2}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt,
  numberfirstline=true, firstnumber=1, stepnumber=5}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{The Title}
\author{author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\Blindtext

{\advance\columnwidth-1em%
\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=1em,float,caption={This is a very long caption, it is so long that it spans two lines.},label=mylisting]
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
  teh c0dez
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good, but still moves the caption so that it does not align with the caption of figures. See the updated mwe.