# Line numbering within pages with listings package

Tags: listings, line-numbering

When I use `listings` package as is, line numbers appear in the margin and the listing lines start at the margin. I know a workaround of putting each listing into a minipage with `\noindent`, but it is tedious.

It there a global setting that could push the line numbers right to begin at the margin?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Sorry to ask that, can you elaborate your question? please...

Comment: Did you already take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340876/134144?

Comment: `\lstset{numbers=left, xleftmargin=1.5em}`, where you set `xleftmargin=...` to a value that suits you